# merging two lists<T> and compare

Tags: c#, .net, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [comparing two List<>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767847/comparing-two-list)

`emp_db_snapshot` - loading from db a fresh copy of what the user have selected in the past:

`emp_selected_by_user` - user selected list, user may change what is already selected or may add more to the list of may remove from the list:

```
//let say i have two rows in the list.
List<Employee> emp_db_snapshot = new List<Employee>();
emp_db_snapshot = EmployeeListFromDB ; //loads the list from db

//let say i have two rows in the list.
List<Employee> emp_selected_by_user = new List<Employee>();
emp_selected_by_user = MySelectedEmployee //loads the list selected by user.


//merging the two lists:
//got total of 4 rows.
List<Employee> allEmployee = emp_db_snapshot.Union(emp_selected_by_user).ToList();
```

so my question is:

how can i differentiate or compare ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for in terms of differentiating. Do you want to exclude duplicates? Or possibly find out which ones exist in both lists?

Comment: @Brian: Sounds like he wants to be able to examine the resulting list `allEmployee` and determine the source of each item - database or selected by user.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question over instead of following up on your initial one.

Comment: I thought I recognized this question... =)

Comment: i updated the question. and not sure which part you guys are not udnerstanding... i just need a way to compare two list

Comment: The code I posted would give you the difference within the Union of the two collections.  This means it would only give you what is difference.  You would then use the Intersection to determine what is the same about the two collections.  I still do not understand the reason your not simply using EmployeeListFromDB and MySelectedEmployee since they are not methods.

Answer (score 1):

I will make an attempt to answer the question.

You could make a collection of the differences between each collection if they happen to have some of the same data.

```
var DifferencesList = ListA.Where(x => !ListB.Any(x1 => x1.id == x.id)).Union(ListB.Where(x => !ListA.Any(x1 => x1.id == x.id)));
```

You could I suppose at that point find the Intersection between the collections and merge that result into the list of Differences.  This would allow you then have a single collection with all the data only appearing once.

Comment: it did not give me what i want... i have a two list each list might be different or same, so what i want is something a list of matching list and a list of not matching list

Comment: @Abu Hamzah - I just told you how to do that. The code I posted would list you the Union of the differences. You would also have to use the Intersection to find both collections have in common.  It is up to you to figure out the rest.  I refuse to simply give you the entire answer.